# PHP count() returns NULL on non-empty array

Tags: php, arrays, php-7.1

I populate a whole bunch of data into an array (either by pulling in from memcache or querying the database). I want to count how many rows are in this array to make sure it's greater than 0.  When I use count(), it returns nothing, even when the array is full of data.

For troubleshooting, I tried the following code:

```
$item_count=count($item_data);
print_r($item_data);
die($item_count);
```

This prints out a huge array that I can see has 146 elements.  But $item_count is NULL. Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks!

As requested in the comments, here's an example of what the array looks like that I'm trying to count:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [calories] => 190
            [healthy_option] => 0
            [name] => Chicken McNuggets
            [url_name] => chicken-mcnuggets
            [category_name] => Chicken Nuggets and Strips
            [category_url_name] => chicken-nuggets-strips
            [category_id] => 85
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [calories] => 380
            [healthy_option] => 0
            [name] => Chicken Selects Premium Breast Strips - 3 piece
            [url_name] => chicken-selects-premium-breast-strips-3-piece
            [category_name] => Chicken Nuggets and Strips
            [category_url_name] => chicken-nuggets-strips
            [category_id] => 85
        )

)
```

Comment: I don't believe `count` can return `null`. Are you sure you're not mis-spelling something? If not, please provide replication example data.

Comment: Try an `echo $item_count` or a `var_dump($item_count);`

Comment: Can't replicate using the example data provided. Have a go on http://3v4l.org and see if you can.

Comment: `die("$item_count");` will work correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [die()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) function behaves like [exit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).
This means that an Integer argument is considered as a "status".

From the doc:

> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0 is used to terminate the program successfully.

If you want to print a value, I recommend you to use something else like echo, print_r, etc.

Do you have the same troubles without using die() ?

Comment: Nice catch, completely missed that one.